# Unable to import BigQuery data into GCP AI Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I had previously used the code below to import data from bigquery to an AI notebook instance in GCP. For unknown reasons it stopped working and gives me the following error: "ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery_storage_v1beta1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)". It may have started after I began cloning my github repository (I delete the AI notebook instance to avoid a charge), but I can't be sure. Thoughts?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows = 200 
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

import numpy as np

query="""
SELECT *
FROM
  [table_name] """

df = bigquery.Client().query(query).to_dataframe()
df.head()
```

Comment: maybe `Goolge` changed code and you should install newer version.

Comment: Try running %pip install goole-cloud-bigquery in a cell of your notebook before running the import

Comment: Have the same problem with the instance just created, problem seems for me to be in: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py Code in there mentions from google.cloud import bigquery_storage_v1beta1 but that doesn't exist anymore as far as I can see, should be bigquery_storage_v1beta2 Don't know how should update this package.

Comment: @rmestves: I tried running the %pip install google-cloud-bigquery before the imports and got the following errors: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement goole-cloud-bigquery (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for goole-cloud-bigquery

Comment: also, when I run the code above (without %pip install) I now get this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transport'

Comment: @Marty my command was lacking a "g"in the gooGle.  Try again %pip install google-cloud-bigquery

Comment: I typed the command in correctly. That wasn't the problem. There is a googleapis/python-bigquery issue noted in github that was exactly the same as mine. I added my two cents to the topic and it is being looked into.

Comment: @Marty I thought that because in the error message you posted its written "goole" too.  Can you share the GitHub issue here?

Comment: @rmsteves here is the github issues link: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/206

Comment: I just got it to work. I first updated with: !sudo /opt/conda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-bigquery google-cloud-bigquery-storage pandas pyarrow --yes. followed by: %pip install google-cloud-bigquery. I really hope this is reproducible.

Comment: @Marty is your problem solved so?

Comment: Frustratingly no. It was working yesterday but now GCP released a new API for AI Notebooks. I activated that API and now I am getting a Forbidden: 403 Access Denied message regarding the Bigquery tables I am trying to query.

Comment: Strike that, I was in the wrong account (grrrrr). Seems to be working now. Important not to forget to restart kernal. @rmsteves I'll give your comment a up arrow since you supplied half the commands needed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good @Marty :)  I'll summarize the solution in a community wiki answer, if you think its fair, consider upvoting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was updating the packages with the following commands:

First:

```
!sudo /opt/conda/bin/conda install -c conda-forge google-cloud-bigquery google-cloud-bigquery-storage pandas pyarrow --yes
```

Then:

```
%pip install google-cloud-bigquery
```